# How to change the smart contract of a collection in Opensea

Tags: nft, smart-contract-wallets, opensea

Although I have contacted the Opensea help center their response time is usually very long. I have therefore decided to debut on their forum with this question.

I have a contract deployed and published as a collection in Opensea that has a small piece of data in the internal logic that should be updated. The problem is that it can only be done by creating a new contract.

As the collection is already published in Opensea I was wondering if it was possible to update the contract address in the published collection, but I don't see what can be done. I also don't see the option to delete the collection.

Obviously the owners of the NFTs will have to receive the new IDs of this new contract, but before doing all this, I would like to know if it is possible to update the contract address in the collection in Opensea, or on the contrary, there will inevitably be two collections with the same name and different contract.

In this case I consider not to make the new one and solve the problem in another way.

Answer (score 0):

If you own the collection then you should be able to edit it's name and external link. You can deploy the new contract, mint the nfts to the owners from the old collection. Change the link of the old collection and name it as deprecated or something. Then update the link of the new contract to match the old one.